# Custom data in jQuery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

on the "update" callback you can get the order of elements with `$(this).sortable('toArray');`

But this order contains the element IDs.

How can I get a custom attribute, like `data-myattr`? I want that order to contain values from this attibute instead of IDs....

```
   $('ul').sortable({
     handle: 'h2'
     items: 'li',
     context: this,
     update: function(){        

       var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');

       // here I want a array of values from my attribute, not ID values...
       alert(order);

       ....

     }
   });
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<ul>
  <li data-myattr="a-1" id="whatever">
    ...
  </li>
  ...
```

Comment: This should probably be a jQuery UI feature request...

Comment: Ok, I read the code and it's actually implemented now! Please upvote my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("ul").sortable({
  .
  .
  .
  update: function(event, ui) {        
    var arr = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    var i, n;
    var attrs = [];
    for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
      attrs.push($('#' + arr[i]).data('myattr'));
    }

    alert(attrs);  
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I had a dummy element in my JSBin script - I've removed it.

Comment: the only downside is that if you have no ID attribute on the elements this will no work :)

Answer (score 42):

As of August '12, this is implemented directly in jQuery UI:

```
var order = $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'data-myattr'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").data("myattr") // if you use jQuery, >= 1.4.3

$("li").attr("data-myattr") // for erlier
```

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kTKzY/)

Comment: @Alper I really hope you will never recommend `data` use anylonger... as you can see on this unit test( http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-jqueryselection-data/8 ) data is slow...use prop cause it's faster(or native js which is even faster).